# HttpURLConnection getInputStream() returns empty for specific device

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, alcatel-ot

Im experiencing a strange behaviour when using HttpURLConnection getInputStream() on a different devices. On all devices except "Alcatel" im getting a valid input stream only for Alcatel devices im getting a different(empty) kind of input stream:

**All devices except alcatel**
[image]

**Alcatel devices**
[image]

Im making the exact same call and getting 200 for all the devices.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
urlObj = new URL(url);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(body.length);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty(HEADER_KEY_CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(body.length));
urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(body);

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show some code. Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you need to have proxy setting for alcatel. httpurlconnection may fail without proper proxy gateway.